# Getting errors related to java security-manager + ExpiringCache.java

Tags: java-8, java-security, spring-resttemplate, javax.xml, java-security-manager

We are using wildfly-9.01. I am getting error/caused while executing action:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 200
    at java.io.ExpiringCache.cleanup(ExpiringCache.java:120)
    at java.io.ExpiringCache.get(ExpiringCache.java:76)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:406)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
    at java.io.FilePermission$1.run(FilePermission.java:215)
    at java.io.FilePermission$1.run(FilePermission.java:203)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.FilePermission.init(FilePermission.java:203)
    at java.io.FilePermission.<init>(FilePermission.java:277)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
    at java.io.File.exists(File.java:814)
    at org.jboss.modules.FileResourceLoader$4.run(FileResourceLoader.java:194)
    at org.jboss.modules.FileResourceLoader$4.run(FileResourceLoader.java:192)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.modules.FileResourceLoader.getResource(FileResourceLoader.java:192)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadResourceLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:343)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadResourceLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:95)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.getResourceAsStream(Module.java:627)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findResourceAsStream(ModuleClassLoader.java:537)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:358)
    at __redirected.__RedirectedUtils.findProviderClassNames(__RedirectedUtils.java:148)
    at __redirected.__RedirectedUtils.loadProvider(__RedirectedUtils.java:103)
    at __redirected.__RedirectedUtils.loadProvider(__RedirectedUtils.java:99)
    at __redirected.__XMLInputFactory.<init>(__XMLInputFactory.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor6.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:193)
    .. 45 more
```

I'm getting this exception while creating a new instance of RestTemplate object.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate()
```

Please refer full stack-trace here

```
2022-08-05 12:06:38,848 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-423) UT005023: Exception handling request to //dashboard: javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider __redirected.__XMLInputFactory could not be instantiated: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 200
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:205)
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:152)
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:265)
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:227)
    at javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance(XMLInputFactory.java:154)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder$XmlObjectMapperInitializer.xmlInputFactory(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:817)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder$XmlObjectMapperInitializer.create(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:807)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:585)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.<init>(RestTemplate.java:167)
    at com.myapp.security.rest.client.SecurityHttpClient.<init>(SecurityHttpClient.java:35)
    at com.myapp.security.rest.client.SecurityHttpClient.<init>(SecurityHttpClient.java:40)
    at com.myapp.security.util.AuthorizationUtil.getUSP(AuthorizationUtil.java:135)
    at com.myapp.security.filter.SecurityFilter.processFilter(SecurityFilter.java:55)
    at com.myapp.security.filter.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:89)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1$1.run(ServletInitialHandler.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:175)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 200
    at java.io.ExpiringCache.cleanup(ExpiringCache.java:120)
    at java.io.ExpiringCache.get(ExpiringCache.java:76)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:406)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
    at java.io.FilePermission$1.run(FilePermission.java:215)
    at java.io.FilePermission$1.run(FilePermission.java:203)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.FilePermission.init(FilePermission.java:203)
    at java.io.FilePermission.<init>(FilePermission.java:277)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
    at java.io.File.exists(File.java:814)
    at org.jboss.modules.FileResourceLoader$4.run(FileResourceLoader.java:194)
    at org.jboss.modules.FileResourceLoader$4.run(FileResourceLoader.java:192)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.modules.FileResourceLoader.getResource(FileResourceLoader.java:192)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadResourceLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:343)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadResourceLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:95)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.getResourceAsStream(Module.java:627)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findResourceAsStream(ModuleClassLoader.java:537)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:358)
    at __redirected.__RedirectedUtils.findProviderClassNames(__RedirectedUtils.java:148)
    at __redirected.__RedirectedUtils.loadProvider(__RedirectedUtils.java:103)
    at __redirected.__RedirectedUtils.loadProvider(__RedirectedUtils.java:99)
    at __redirected.__XMLInputFactory.<init>(__XMLInputFactory.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor6.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:193)
    .. 45 more
```

Any suggestions for things to look at or try to avoid such issue?

Comment: I found one more git thread which have a similar kind of issue.
https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues/230

Comment: What is the exact Java version you're using?

Comment: This is an interesting issue. At the first glance, it looks impossible. At the second, there might be a corner case if the cache changes in between the `cleanup` method, which is only possible if some Instrumentation is going on which triggers another file permission check exactly at this point. This should sort itself out in newer Java versions due to [JDK-8164705](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8164705). That’s why the linked issue on JDK-11 is said to be solved with `sun.io.useCanonCaches=false` and `sun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false` (which is the default in JDK 12 and newer).